# How can a structure have dynamically allocated members in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, dynamic, malloc

I have tried to dynamically allocate an object as member of a structure with this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define width 4

struct foo{
     int* p1 = malloc(sizeof(*p1) * width);   
};
```

but the compilers, both clang and gcc, throw the error:

```
error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '=' token
```

when I attempt to compile the code; here is the link: https://godbolt.org/z/-Sy6CK.

My question:

- How can I create a structure that has dynamically allocated members in C?

Comment: You can't have initialization inline in a structure. You must do the initialization in a function.

Comment: First, you define it as a pointer w/o assigning any value, like `int *p1;`, then down there, in some other function, you can allocate memory and assign the pointers value to point to the allocated memory space, like `p1 = malloc(n * sizeof(someVarOrStruct));`.

Comment: By the way, if the `width` is a compile-time constant (as shown in the question) then why use pointers and dynamic allocation to begin with? Why not an array, as in `int p1[width];`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It´s correct what you said, but I´d wanted to just make the example as simple as possible to go "straight to the case" without too many distraction from other things. The main reason to choose dynamic allocation is to resize the member later on, if required.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What have guided me is the handling from C++. In C++, it is possible to immediately allocate the memory for a member of a `struct` or `class` by using `new`:`struct foo{ int* p1 = new int;  
};` But again of course, C isn´t C++ and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define width 4

// declaration, you can't do initialisation here
struct foo{
     int* p1;
};

int main()
{
  struct foo bar;

  bar.p1 = malloc(sizeof(*bar.p1) * width);   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Or this:

```
struct foo{
     int* p1;
};

int main()
{
  struct foo bar = {.p1 = malloc(sizeof(*bar.p1) * width)};
}
```

or

```
int main()
{
    struct {
        int* p1;
    } bar = {.p1 = malloc(sizeof(*bar.p1) * width)};
}
```

Comment: I´m quite fascinated about this technique. Can I initialize more members of `bar` if `foo` would had more members by using the curly brackets method? like: `struct foo bar = {.p1 = malloc(sizeof(*bar.p1) * width)} {.c = 24};` if `foo` had the additional member `int c;`?